# Async event not firing in Powershell Core 6

Tags: powershell-core

I have a powershell module that uses async timer events to monitor and trigger actions.

It works fine when kicked off in the powershell terminal in windows.

I was interested to find out if it would run, as is, using Powershell Core on Raspberry Pi. It almost does!

The async events do not appear to fire correctly, but then I noticed that, if I interact with the terminal, I'll start to see the Verbose log statements spitting out and then the async events will fire. So for example, I know my script should add a timer event to trigger in 10 seconds - but it will never trigger - but if I interact with the terminal (even press the Esc key is enough), the verbose logs will spit out, I can see the timer event being logged and it will successfully fire.

Any thoughts on this? Any ideas about how to initiate the script so that it will work as expected and how it does work under the powershell terminal in windows? My idea for a work-around would be to have a synchronous infinite loop that would run after the async part was kicked off, to keep things alive and mimic me interacting with the terminal. But would prefer if there was a cleaner way to kick things off on the Raspberry Pi and have it work correctly.

Comment: Just to close off this question as it's been open without comment for a year.
I've also asked the question in MS PS Core forum, but no suggestions about why it works fine in a Windows PowerShell terminal session, but won't on a Linux PS terminal.
So I did go ahead and implement a work-around that's neat enough and acceptable IMO.
For anyone reading this and having similar problems, you can view the code in this project and see how I got it to work:
https://github.com/cathalmchale/hue

Answer (score 0):

For solution / work-around for Linux PS Core background events not firing in the same way they do on PowerShell for Windows, see this project:
https://github.com/cathalmchale/hue

In particular see this Pester unit test:
https://github.com/cathalmchale/hue/blob/master/Hue.Script/Hue.Script.Tests.ps1

The BDD-style test, with Given, When, Then notation asks and answers the question:
Given: A script module running in Powershell Core on Pi.
When: Start lights monitor in keep-alive mode.
Then: Polling loop is entered.

This infinite / polling loop allows the background events to fire on the Linux PS Core Terminal session.